# how do retrieve specific row in Hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a dataset looks like this:

```
---------------------------
 cust | cost | cat   | name
---------------------------
  1   |  2.5 | apple | pkLady
---------------------------
  1   |  3.5 | apple | greenGr
---------------------------
  1   |  1.2 | pear  | yelloPear
----------------------------
  1   |  4.5 | pear  |  greenPear
-------------------------------
```

my hive query should now compare the cheapest price of each item the customer bought. So I want now to get the 2.5 and 1.2 into one row to get its difference. Since I am new to Hive I don't now how to ignore everything else until I reach next category of item while I still kept the cheapest price in the previous category.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the expected output, specifically, what you mean by "how to ignore everything else until I reach next category of item while I still kept the cheapest price in the previous category"?

Comment: After I read first row and remembered the 2.5 and I want to traverse the rows until I found next category pear in this case pear and compare the price and then remember 1.2 from pear and traverse again until I found next item and do the same.

Comment: So you want to add a `min(cost)` column for each cust? The `cat` column isn't relevant, right?

Comment: accepted answer is technically correct but highly inefficient given alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a subquery containing the minimum cost for each customer, and then join it to the original table:

```
select
    mytable.*,
    minCost.minCost,
    cost - minCost as costDifference
from mytable
inner join
    (select
       cust,
       min(cost) as minCost
    from mytable
    group by cust) minCost
on mytable.cust = minCost.cust
```

I created an [interactive SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa93c5/3) using MySQL, but it should work just fine in Hive.

Comment: this takes 2 MR jobs.

Answer (score 2):

you can use like below:

```
select cat,min(cost) from table group by cost;
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your options ([brickhouse UDFs](https://github.com/klout/brickhouse), [hive windowing functions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+WindowingAndAnalytics) or a self-join) in Hive, a self-join is the *worst* way to do this.

```
select *
  , (cost - min(cost) over (partition by cust)) cost_diff
from table
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is really a SQL question rather than a Hive question: If you just want the cheapest cost per customer you can do

```
select cust, min(cost)
group by cust
```

Otherwise if you want the cheapest cost per customer per category you can do:

```
select cust, cat, min(cost)
from yourtable
groupby cust, cat
```